# Importing C# dlls in Nodejs with Edge

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, dll, compilation

Right now I am trying to write a little piece of code in nodejs to access some methods we have used in other projects. To accomplish this I've installed some module called edge which allows you to write actual C# code in your nodejs project as long as you have .NET 4.5 installed. However the C# code I am trying to run uses some DLL which is imported by using the `DLLImport` attribute.

When trying to import the DLL I'm getting this error: 
*An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B).*

Googling about this error made me realise there is something up with the way the DLL is built (however it works fine in the project I got it from). I find  that people encountering this problem usually built  their DLL for a 32-bit system while they were running a 64-bit system.

Both the server this DLL is run on and the computer Im working on are 64-bit systems.

This is the code I am working with now (it's just a test version to see if I can get it to work).

Documentation about edge can be found here: https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge

```
var edge = require('edge');

var run = edge.func(function(){/*

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class OtherClass
{
    static string path = "C:/test/path";

    private static object writeLock = new object();

    [DllImport("testDLL")]
    private static extern int Write(string path, string voice, string text, string file);

    public static void TTS_Write(string text, string voice, string id, string guid)
    {
        string path = string.Format("C:/Users/Kay/Desktop/{0}_{1}.wav", guid, id);

        lock (writeLock)
            Write(path, voice, text, path);
    }
}    

public class Startup
{
    public async Task<object> Invoke(object input)
    {
        OtherClass.TTS_Write("text to be spoken", "Klaus22k_HQ", "1234", "123343");

        return "Hello World";
    }
}*/

});

run("void", function(error, result){
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Note that the C# code is between /*  */ as this is syntax for edge (and thus the code is actually run).

This code crashes when it hits `Write(path, voice, text, path);` which is an external method.

My knowledge about compiling code really isn't that broad so I'm probably missing some obvious stuff.
My question is: How is it possible to import this DLL the way it is done in the example, if possible at all? Are there alternatives?

Comment: An alternative may be to create another program that does what you need that you call from the nodejs solution. The other program would listen on some type of IPC for commands, execute them, and return a response when finished so the nodejs knows its been completed.

Comment: I've created a small project that does just that though I'm getting some annoying results from the DLL I'm pinvoking (unrelated to this issue Im sure).
How would I then call the functions in that other program again though?